After packaging with scrapyd-deploy, Scrapy fails to run
Before packaging, Scrapy was running normally, but after packaging with scrapyd-deploy, it failed to run. The log showed up to [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 481caacdc0d9e79c, and then it disappeared. Later, I found that if I disabled EXTENSIONS and re-packaged, it could run normally. However, the items in EXTENSIONS are necessary. What should I do?
2024-08-16 17:37:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.9.0 started (bot: EcSpider)
2024-08-16 17:37:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 5.1.0.0, libxml2 2.12.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 22.10.0.rc1, Python 3.7.16 (default, May 23 2023, 14:46:23) - [GCC 10.2.1 20210110], pyOpenSSL 24.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024), cryptography 42.0.3, Platform Linux-4.15.0-162-generic-x86_64-with-debian-11.7
2024-08-16 17:37:20 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'EcSpider',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 30,
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'LOG_FILE': '/app/logs/EcSpider/EcProductCostAll/2024-08-16T17_37_17.log',
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'EcSpider.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['EcSpider.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2024-08-16 17:37:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 481caacdc0d9e79c

I disabled EXTENSIONS and re-packaged, it could run normally. However, the items in EXTENSIONS are necessary
Scrapy suddenly stopped like this, without any error log notifications

if you want to disable telnet extension you can simply do it from the settings
TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

stopped  INFO: Overridden settings

can you share the logs ? and if possible minimal code to reproduce this ?
